# How to format Form Field title with the appropriate currency in Python/Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a a form where a form field's title includes a currency amount

```
class MyForm(form.Forms):
     currency_field = forms.BooleanField()

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self.fields['currency_field'].widget.attrs = {'title':'By checking this field, you can avail our services for $75'}
```

You can see that I have hardcoded $75 into this. Is there way to format this in the local currency.

Comment: Do you mean local to the server or local to the user? If the server, it's probably easier to hard-code. If the user, you would need to get their location, convert that to currency, then find and apply an exchange rate. This would be an app in itself!